# No module named numpy found (Mas OSX)

Tags: python-2.7

I recently installed the Eclipse Python plugin and have come across this error whenever I use:

```
import numpy as np
```

When I try to import numpy I get an error saying that

> "No module named numpy found".

Using terminal, I checked my version of Python and it is 2.7 though I do have other versions installed on my mac. How would I go about fixing this error?

EDIT: It seems that I also get a similar error when importing cv2.

Comment: You may have to download and install numpy. I don't believe it comes bundled with an ordinary Python install.

Comment: Well I found the latest version of numpy (1.9.1 if that's correct), but how do I install it exactly and what directory should I put it in?

Comment: Is `pip install numpy` not working?

Comment: I've tried running the command in terminal, but it returns a "-bash: pip: command not found" message.